# Bottender - Adding custom routes - express server

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, bots, bottender

I want to add custom routes to a [bottender](https://github.com/Yoctol/bottender) that uses [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) as a server. But when I do, the route used by bottender(supposed to be `/messenger`) returns 404. here's how it looks like

**index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { MessengerBot } = require('bottender');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { registerRoutes } = require('bottender/express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const compression = require('compression');

const handler = require('./handlers');
const { messenger } = require('./config');
const logger = require('./utils/logger');

const errorController = require('./controllers/errorController');
const ticketsController = require('./controllers/ticketsController');

const { APP_PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const server = express();

/* istanbul ignore next */
const verify = (req, res, buf) => {
  req.rawBody = buf.toString();
};

server.use('/images', express.static('images'));
server.use('/facebook-payment', express.static('payment-page/build'));
server.use(compression());
server.use(helmet());
server.use(cors());
server.use(bodyParser.json({ verify }));
server.use(require('morgan')('short', { stream: logger.logStream }));

const router = express.Router();
/* Custom APIs */
server.use('/api', router);
server.use('/api/tickets', ticketsController.getByEventId);

/* Error Handling */
server.use(errorController.error404);
server.use(errorController.generalError);

const bots = {
  messenger: new MessengerBot(messenger.bot).onEvent(handler.messenger.execute),
  // Define other platform bots here!
};

registerRoutes(server, bots.messenger, messenger.server);
// Start server
server.listen(APP_PORT, () => logger.info(`ENV[${NODE_ENV}] - server is listening on port ${APP_PORT}...`));

module.exports = server;
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  messenger: {
    profile,
    bot: {
      accessToken: FB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      appId: APP_ID,
      appSecret: APP_SECRET,
      mapPageToAccessToken: bots.getTokenByPageById,
    },
    server: {
      verifyToken: FB_VERIFY_TOKEN,
      path: '/messenger',
    },
  },
};
```

Any leads as to why the route used by bottender returns 404?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you got this 404 status code from a `POST /messenger` request?

Comment: yes, `POST /messenger` gives 404

Comment: Maybe a minimal reproducible example can help us deep into the problem. Do you mind create a GitHub repo to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: found the culprit! thanks for looking though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what's the implementation of your `errorController`, you may want to try to put `registerRoutes()` before them.

Such as:

```
// register before error handling
const bots = { /* your bots */}
registerRoutes(server, bots.messenger, messenger.server);

/* Error Handling */
server.use(errorController.error404);
server.use(errorController.generalError);

server.listen(/* ... */)
```

Comment: yeah true. you posted answer 4sec faster than me :). i tested it and it's the culprit

Answer (score 1):

I been able to fix the issue by using the `registerRoutes` **first** before registering the custom APIs. So code looks like this

```
const { registerRoutes } = require('bottender/express');

/* register bottender/express route */
registerRoutes(server, bots.messenger, messenger.server); // needs to be declared first before error handler
/* Error Handling */
app.use(errorController.error404);
app.use(errorController.generalError);
```